# XML signature validation against remote certificate, with PHP

Tags: php, validation, saml, xml-signature

I'm working on a project where I need to validate an embedded signature in an XML file (SAML assertion) against a public key located on a remove server.

Has anyone done this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you are looking for lies within the documentation of PHP in the user comments:

[openssl_verify() - User Comment](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-verify.php#62526)

That should help you out. And just remember, as long as you can fetch the cert file, you can use [cURL()](http://www.php.net/curl) to fetch that instead of fread, if it is needed (or at least in theory you should be able to).